# init() is unavailable in AVCaptureDeviceInput in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift4, xcode9, avcapturedevice

I have a view controller in my application that shows the back camera like Snapchat and it was worked well in Swift 3, but when I updated to Swift 4, the compiler won't let me run it because of the following error:

> `init()` is unavailable for `AVCaptureDeviceInput`

This view controller should show the camera without any button or extra things just like Snapchat. So, here is the full view controller code:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class cameraViewController: UIViewController , UIImagePickerControllerDelegate , UINavigationControllerDelegate {

var captureSession : AVCaptureSession?

var stillImageOutput : AVCaptureStillImageOutput?

var previewLayer : AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?

var imagePicker: UIImagePickerController!

@IBOutlet weak var cameraView: UIView!

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    previewLayer?.frame = cameraView.bounds
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)


    captureSession = AVCaptureSession()

    captureSession?.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720

    let backCamera = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)

    let error : NSError?

    var input = AVCaptureDeviceInput()

    do {
        input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: backCamera)
    }
    catch {
        //  error
    }

    if error == nil && (captureSession?.canAddInput(input))! {

        captureSession?.addInput(input)

        stillImageOutput = AVCaptureStillImageOutput()

        stillImageOutput?.outputSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey : AVVideoCodecJPEG]


        if (captureSession?.canAddOutput(stillImageOutput))! {

            captureSession?.addOutput(stillImageOutput)

            previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)

            previewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill

            previewLayer?.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait

            cameraView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer!)

            captureSession?.startRunning() 

        }
    }

}

}
```

I can't run the application because of this line:

```
var input = AVCaptureDeviceInput()
```

Comment: Keep in mind that the user can revoke the camera usage authorization (SessionSetupResult) at any time. You should always check it before trying to access it. Besides that You should make sure you are doing that at the main queue. Apple has released its AVCam sample version 7. You should use that as a reference https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: If you run into trouble when building it you need to change `photoSettings.availablePreviewPhotoPixelFormatTypes` to `photoSettings.__availablePreviewPhotoPixelFormatTypes` and `photoSettings.availablePreviewPhotoPixelFormatTypes` to `photoSettings.__availablePreviewPhotoPixelFormatTypes`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so I used all of the left codes inside do catch and I got the result and the app is working well in the swift 4 - so instead of view will appear in my question codes use this codes below

```
 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)


    captureSession = AVCaptureSession()

    captureSession?.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720


    do {
        let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: .defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo))

        captureSession?.addInput(input)

        stillImageOutput = AVCaptureStillImageOutput()

        stillImageOutput?.outputSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey : AVVideoCodecJPEG]


        if (captureSession?.canAddOutput(stillImageOutput))! {

            captureSession?.addOutput(stillImageOutput)

            previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)

            previewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill

            previewLayer?.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait

            cameraView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer!)

            captureSession?.startRunning()

        }



    } catch {

        print(error)

    }

}
```

I have answered my question to help other people

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 4, you have to specify a device in order to initialize `AVCaptureDeviceInput` - in fact, you are **already initializing it** with one two lines after the code that throws the error.

Moreover, you are implicitly unwrapping an otherwise safely unwrapped `AVCaptureSession` in the `if` statement right after that.

Here is your code, polished:

```
do {
    guard let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: backCamera),
        captureSession = captureSession else {
        print("Error in initializing a device input")
    }

    if error == nil && (captureSession.canAddInput(input)) {

    [...]
}
catch let error {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use like below:

```
if let backCamera = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video) {
    do {
        var input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: backCamera)
    } catch {
        //  error
    }
}
```

How to use in your code :

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    captureSession?.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.hd1280x720

    guard let backCamera = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video) else {
        print("AVCaptureDevice backCamera is nil")
        return
    }

    let error : NSError?

    do {
        let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: backCamera)

        if (captureSession?.canAddInput(input))! {
            captureSession?.addInput(input)
            stillImageOutput = AVCaptureStillImageOutput()
            stillImageOutput?.outputSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey : AVVideoCodecJPEG]

            if (captureSession?.canAddOutput(stillImageOutput!))! {
                captureSession?.addOutput(stillImageOutput!)
                previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession!)
                previewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
                previewLayer?.connection?.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait
                cameraView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer!)
                captureSession?.startRunning()
            }
        }
    }
    catch {
        //  error
    }
}
```

Comment: it doesn't worked for me :( it says type of string has no member video

Comment: Can you post how you are using?

Comment: I used this codes that you wrote here instead of do catch in my codes is that true or not?

Comment: You are doing something wrong while calling ‘.video’

Comment: can you edit your answer with full code of the class please?